# Getting transactions using plaid on a mortgage account

Tags: python, plaid

I'm using plaid to get my bank transactions. I have a mortgage account for which I have working access tokens. I'm able to make an API call to that bank account using the python SDK:

```
retDict = self.client.Transactions.get(self.tokens[bank_name], start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

I get a valid response with the right bank info, the right balance, but no transactions no matter the start_date and today values. This code works just fine with other institutions (checking account, credit card account). Is there something that needs to be done differently for a mortgage account?
Is this behavior expected?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking!  This is expected behavior; /transactions/get doesn't currently support mortgage accounts -- currently the only loan-type account it supports is student loan accounts.  This isn't at all clear from the current docs; I'm working on a docs edit that will make this more explicit.